# formatting a string column in csv in a sybase understandable date time format

Tags: unix, awk, sybase

I've a csv file with many column along with two columns having date and time as 'ddmmyyyy' and 'hhmmss'. I want to convert this file inot another csv file such as can bcp it into a sybase table.
  I am using awk for that. But now i get an issue where i want to convert these date and time column to a single column with format 'yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:SS' so as to use in sybase.
How can i do this in awk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The long way using `awk`:

```
awk '{ printf "%s-%s-%sT%s:%s:%s\n", substr($1, 5), substr($1, 3, 2), substr($1, 0, 2), substr($2, 0, 2), substr($2, 3, 2), substr($2, 5, 2) }' file.txt
```

Results:

```
yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:SS
```